# I have multiple queries want to merge all query results into the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
table1:                     table2
studentname                StudentAge   
 stuart                      18
```

I have  following queries like 
1)

```
select studentname as sname from table1;
  sname
  Stuart
```

2)

```
select StudentAge as age from table2;
  age
  18
```

I want to display the query results in a table having two columns as:

```
 category         Values
  sname          Stuart
  age              18
```

Comment: Do your tables really have only one row?  How are the rows lined up in the different tables?

Comment: There is absolutely no relationship between the 2 tables so this is impossible.(unless you accept the the resultant rows have no relationship - in which case union (as in answers and comments for you previous questions on this topic).

Comment: Can you post full structure of both the tables so if there is any relationship then we can help you for this

Comment: UNION ALL the tables. cast the integer column as varchar.

Answer (score 1):

If your tables have at most one row, you can use subqueries:

```
select (select studentname from table1) as sname
       (select StudentAge from table2) as age
```

Comment: I have more than one rows

Comment: @vivekSB . . . Then ask a new question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  This answers the question that you have asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Given the data you've presented, with only a single row in each table, you can use a CROSS JOIN to join them:

```
select t1.studentname, t2.StudentAge
  from table1 t1
  cross join table2 t2
```

This will perform a Cartesian join, where each row in each table is joined to every row in the other table, and the number of returned rows is the product of the number of rows in the two tables.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d43a5ec0268e54f21ab290687bf2781b)

Answer (score 0):

This suggests me `union all` :

```
select t.category, t.values
from ( (select t.studentname as values, 'studentname' as category from table1 t) union all
       (select t.stuedentage, 'age' as category from table2 t)
     ) t;
```