# I have multiple queries want to merge all query results into the same table with two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  following queries like

1. select studentname as sname from table1;

   sname
    stuart
2. select StudentAge as age from table2;

   age
     18

I want to display the query results in a table having two columns as:
 category         Values
  sname          Stuart
  age              18

Comment: This question been posted multiple times.  What wrong with answers ?

Comment: The answer I gave to the first time you asked this answers this question. You really need to ask a better question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61342251/i-have-multiple-queries-want-to-merge-all-query-results-into-the-same-table#comment108518749_61342251

Answer (score 0):

```
Select studentname, studentage from table1 join table2 using(studentID)
```

The two tables must have a same key. Put this key in the "using"